# Launch a specific Pod via API and connect from outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am currently designing a system where users should be able to start a simulation through a Web Portal and then connect to it with a gRPC client (amongst other things). After the user is finished the simulation then terminates. I want to run the whole system in a kind of microservice architecture in a kubernetes cluster if possible. This is however my first time working with kubernetes and I am unsure if it is possible to achieve this.

As far as I could gather from reading the documentation and googling around it seems like I should be able to launch a pod by calling [POST /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#create-pod-v1-core) and making it availble under the Host IP by setting `hostPort`. However what I dont know is how I would determine a free port on the Node to deploy to or let kubernetes decide that (if `hostPort` is even the correct choice for this). After that it should be pretty straightforward. Send the user the IP:Port to connect to and he just plugs that into his gRPC client.

Any suggestions on how to best achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `hostPort` is rather not recommended, so you'd be better off by specifying a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and access your Pod via a service. In your case you can define `NodePort` service and let Kubernetes decide on the port. Then, fetch the service port using Kubernetes API.

Comment: So would I then create a Pod with a unique label and a NodePort service which selects the Pod based on the unique Label? Just to be clear, each user can start multiple simulations. But he has to be able to connect to one specific simulation.

Comment: Yes, you can distinguish Pods/Services by labels. That's a good approach,